# Exporting multiple dynamic array data to a CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, export-to-csv

My aim is generate a list of numbers converted to even, odd, and fibonacci. However I would like to export the results of the generated numbers on screen to a CSV file. I would like to store all the dynamic results in an array to pass to the export function. My Export works with static array data but my challenge is how to store the multiple dynamic array data in one array to pass to the export function.

How to store the array results from function call in $content array?

```
$content = array($evenNumbers,$oddNumbers,$fibonacci);

> <?php
> 
>     //request form actions using hidden form field
>     $job = (!isset($_REQUEST["job"])) ? '' : trim($_REQUEST["job"]);
> 
>     $export = (!isset($_REQUEST["export"])) ? '' : trim($_REQUEST["export"]);
> 
>     $evenNumbers = array();
> 
>     $oddNumbers = array();
>     $fibonacci = array();
>     $file = new FileDataClass();
> 
>     //performed when user click upload button
>     if ($job == "uploadFile") {
>         
>         //get file from file upload in form 
>         $file->FileData($_FILES["aNumbers"]);
> 
>         $evenNumbers = $file->GetEvenNumbers();
>         $fibonacci = $file->GetFibonacciNumbers();
>         $oddNumbers = $file->GetOddNumbers();
>     }
> 
> 
>     //performed when user click export button
>     
>     elseif($export == "exportFile"){
> 
> 
> 
> 
>         //get file from file upload in form 
>         $file->FileData($_FILES["aNumbers"]);
> 
>         $evenNumbers = $file->GetEvenNumbers();
>         $fibonacci = $file->GetFibonacciNumbers();
>         $oddNumbers = $file->GetOddNumbers();
> 
>     
> 
>         $content = array($evenNumbers,$oddNumbers,$fibonacci);
> 
>     
>    
>     // csv file name 
>     $filename  = "exportnumbers.csv";
> 
> 
>  
>  
> 
>     //pass file name and array of content to export
>     
>      
>           $file->ExportNumbers($content,$filename);
>     
>     }
>     ...
> 
> ?>
```

Comment: We do not know what the `FileDataClass` object is or the other called functions. Plus, we cannot see the printed screen output. What is structure of arrays (simple, nested, etc.)? Please show current output and desired results in csv.

Answer (score -2):

refer to fputcsv() manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php.
Here is an example from above link.

```
<?php

    $list = array (
        array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
        array('123', '456', '789'),
        array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
    );

    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks Im using fputcsv the correct way but my challenge is getting the content from printed on the screen after the user submit the form. pass the content results to the export function. storing the content in the array does not work this way  $content = array($evenNumbers,$oddNumbers,$fibonacci);

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10775548)

Comment: @worldofjr, I agree. I have also added the code but I just realised that it is not visible for some reason. If I go to edit mode, I can see the code.

Comment: Any idea how can I access the data generated form submission to pass to  the export function? I have two if statements to listen for submit and export button click.